# Redirect loop creating a Drupal 7 multisite

Tags: drupal-7, installation, subdomain

I know there are a few questions related to this one, yet I haven't been able to answer mine.

I want to develop 2 websites pointing to the same Drupal files.

so :

drupal1.example.com should point /www/dev/sites/drupal1.example.com
drupal2.example.com should point to /www/dev/sites/drupal2.example.com

I've created both subdomains to point to /www/dev/ folder, so I guess Drupal should "check" from where the traffic orinigates and use the proper sites folder.

I've put settings.php in drupal1.example.com et default.settings.php (with no DB info) in drupal2.example.com but it seems both subdomains use drupal1.example.com sites folder (drupal2 shouldn't be working, it should point me to the install.php folder).

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand your question but I thought this might help you: http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

Comment: Multisite doesn't work on many OS's and devices, Alex.  You may need to use multiple directories.

Comment: @nmc What he's saying is he installed example_site1 via example_site1.com, and example_site2.com is just giving him example_site1.com (not an installer).  This is because his site is using `sites/default/settings.php` not `sites/example_site1/settings.php`.  It's the most common problem encountered when attempting to install multisite on Windows.  There are thousands of unanswered questions like this in the drupal forums, on this site, and just generally splattered all over the Internet.  The d.o official Getting Started multisite install instructions are incomplete--they don't work.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Interesting. Thanks for that. I've never tried Drupal on a Windows server.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 thanks for your comment!  There are indeed many unanswered questions related to that issue.  My problem was encountered on an Apache Linux server though.  I managed to create another DB with a fresh install (I exported the tables from another fresh installation) and, with the right DB info in my new sites/example_site1/settings.php, the fresh Drupal worked like a charm and example_site2.com was still working with the old pages/modules, etc ...  It seems to be a problem related to the installation process.

Comment: @Alex What step was it that was the trouble?  The db info was wrong in the settings.php file for site1?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 No it's just that installation process won't start if I put the right DB info in my site1/settings.php.  I had to create the DB and import a fresh SQL install, then reload my site1 and I could see my empty site1 website working.